# When do we say "let's use %ROWTYPE" and not %TYPE?

Tags: oracle, plsql

1. If I have a table `myTable` with around 15 columns and I want to SELECT just around 5 columns, is it worth it to have a `rec myTable%ROWTYPE` (the 10 cols will not be used at all) or just create a `TYPE rec...` and manually create fields like `(col1 myTable.col1%TYPE...)` for all 5 columns?
2. Up to what extent do we usually create manual types vs rowtypes?
3. How do I declare a rowtype for SELECT queries with joins? for example `rec tableA%ROWTYPE` + probably another field or 2 from `tableB` but all in 1 record type? Do I create it manually? (If only PLSQL has something like "extends" or record inheritance.

Sorry for the long questions, I hope I make sense.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preference is to always use the %ROWTYPE, or better yet a cursor FOR loop, to declare the variables.  Back In The Day (tm) we used to worry A LOT about memory use, and thus declaring individual fields might have made sense if it saved us a few bytes.  But nowadays, IMO, when we have memory space measured in gigabytes the greater code complexity outweighs the value of saving a few bytes.  As far as execution speed goes - oh, please.  We're in a world where some of the most common languages run under a **virtual machine**.  I've spent hours hand-optimizing assembler to wring the last freaking cycle out of tight loop.  Java makes me laugh.  If we're running software under VM's what we're saying is "We've got too many cycles to burn!".

To address each issue:

1. I prefer using cursor FOR loops for just about everything.  This is part of continually trying to answer Cunningham's Question - "What's The Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work?".  IMO using rowtype variables is The Simplest Thing.  Using them eliminates the need to deal with NO_DATA_FOUND and TOO_MANY_ROWS exceptions explicitly - so I'll favor

   ```
   FOR aRow IN (SELECT col1, col2, col3
                  FROM myTable
                  WHERE some_col = some_value)
   LOOP
     NULL;  -- do something useful here
   END LOOP;
   ```

   over

   ```
   DECLARE
     var1  myTable.COL1%TYPE;
     var2  myTable.COL2%TYPE;
     var3  myTable.COL3%TYPE;
   BEGIN
     SELECT col1, col2, col3
       INTO var1, var2, var3
       FROM myTable
       WHERE some_col = some_value;

     NULL;  -- do something useful here
   EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       NULL;  -- do something appropriate here
     WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
       NULL;  -- do something appropriate here
   END;
   ```

   even if I know that `some_col` is unique - largely because where I work what is unique today can be made non-unique tomorrow at the whim of some developer on some team I don't even know exists.  It's called "defensive programming", and if it keeps me from being called at 2:00 AM I'm a happy camper.

   Someone's going to complain that doing this requires the overhead of opening a cursor when it isn't absolutely necessary.  In a whole bunch of years of programming I have **never** encountered a situation where doing this slowed a program down so much that the code had to be rewritten to use a stand-alone singleton SELECT.  I suppose that somewhere in the dark depths of the digital jungle, out in the wilds where clock speeds are still measured in single-digit megahertz, memory is measured in kilobytes, those bytes have only got seven bits, and the Ravenous Bugblatter Beast of Traal awaits the un-towelled this may not apply - but where I'm at (and believe me, the cutting edge it ain't) it's a good-enough strategy.
2. I very seldom create stand-alone variables to hold the results of SELECTs or cursors, largely because of Rule #1 above.
3. To correctly quote Obi-Wan, "Use the cursor FOR loop, Luke!". (Seriously - that's what he really said.  All the "force" stuff is just a bunch of junk dreamed up by some hard-of-hearing film director.  Feh!).  Writing something like

   ```
   FOR aRow IN (SELECT *
                  FROM table1 t1
                  INNER JOIN table2 t2 on (t2.fieldx = t1.fieldx)
                  INNER JOIN table3 t3 on (t3.fieldy = t2.fieldy))
   LOOP
     NULL;  -- whatever
   END LOOP;
   ```

   is, once again, The Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work.  Simpler is gooder.

:-)

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Wow, thank you for this sir! This does makes a lot of sense. 
But I am afraid we are required to have each SELECT query wrapped inside a function and this function is called by a "main()" procedure.

With this nature, I'm not sure how to apply the above solution because I am required to define a TYPE that the function can RETURN and which the PROCEDURE knows about.

Answer (score 0):

Good place to start is the documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/overview.htm#sthref159

(Oracle Database PL/SQL User's Guide and Reference)

Than improve it with a article written by Steven Feuerstein:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-may/o32plsql-1578019.html